# Avoid double click event from being fires when clicked between column resize regions

Tags: c#, datagridview, resize, double-click

I have a DataGridView with few columns. I have a row selected by default every  time the Grid is loaded. So whenever I double click on any row, the code present in the Double Click event gets executed.

Now as I mouse hover between the column headers, the mouse cursor changes and I can start resizing the columns. But, whenever I double click in that same region, the double click event fires and the code present inside it executes.
[image: the region where double click fires]

So I'm unable to verify in the code, how to differentiate if I have double clicked on the rows or the column resizing regions.

Kindly help me find a workaround on the issue. Thanks !!

Comment: There are many `xxxDoubleClick` events provided by the `DataGridView`, may be you should subscribe to the one (or more) that best fits the action you want to perform. e.g. `CellDoubleClick`, `CellContentDoubleClick`, `RowHeaderMouseDoubleClick` etc.

Comment: Try checking the MouseEventArgs!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just used a below shown check to avoid the the double click firing when either column headers/ separator were double clicked. This worked for me.

```
    private void dgvConnections_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
                //Ensure the double click isn't firing when the mouse is clicked anywhere over the column headers/ column separators. 
                DataGridView.HitTestInfo hit = dgvConnections.HitTest(((MouseEventArgs)e).X, ((MouseEventArgs)e).Y);
                if (hit.RowIndex == -1)
                    return;
        //my code here, which should run on double click
    }
```

Comment: This is BRILLIANT!  Who knew that simply casting the event args to MouseEventArgs would yield X and Y coords!  Brilliant @pradeepradyumna

Answer (score 1):

Make sure RowIndex not equal to -1 in your double click event.

`if(e.RowIndex !=-1)
   {
      //   your code
   }`

Comment: Unfortunately there is no RowIndex property available for EventArgs of DataGridView's double click. Can you please suggest any other workaround?